# How to avoid using perl in $PATH and use Host perl when using SDK

Tags: linux

I am using a SDK tool-chain to build my application on Linux, I use `perl` to generate makefiles. when i started using the SDK, it picks up SDK's `perl`, but i want to continue to use host `perl` only.

when i browsed i found the info that, if we use `hash-bang` line `#!/usr/bin/perl` at the start of the file, it always picks up `/usr/bin/Perl` only when you don't call as `perl a.pl`. unfortunately i have to call my perl script using `perl` command only.

are there any options which i can pass to `hash-bang` line to avoid checking in the directories in `$PATH`

Comment: Usually such things is done either by temporary changing the `$PATH` environment variable or by defining an `alias`.

Comment: No, i don't want to change the `$PATH`, because it has other exe's which i want to use.

Comment: In that case define an `alias` for  a single command: `alias perl=/path/to/host/perl`.

Comment: You need to define it in any of the processes that the final script is forked from. Aliases are handed down.

Comment: it did not work out.`alias perl='/usr/bin/perl'`

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work out"? Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder. What does a `which perl` give without and with that alias definition. And what do you actually want?

Comment: Certainly no one can propose a solution without understanding what you want, that is true. But that certainly is not the fault of the person trying to help, is it? ;-) About that alias: if the `which` command points to the SDK, then the alias is _not_ present in that process.

Comment: I renamed the exe name of perl in SDK folder.. now it picks up the host perl.. it is working.. but still it's a work around..